# How to create route that goes to an anchor tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, anchor

I have a one page layout with sections.  But, I also have a couple pages that are separate from the main page.  I want the user experience to be seamless when they navigate from the main page, to the satellite pages, and back.  I can link_to the anchor tag, but then I end up with the anchor in the url...  I want a route to handle it so that the anchor is not in the url...

Is there a way to build a route that will go to an anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK anchors are thrown away by the web-server. It's purely a client-side thing.